# How can I run DavMail from the command-line (or are there any alternatives?)

Tags: command-line, outlook-web-access

Microsoft Outlook, the mistress of many a company - requiring constant attention, and preventing you from using an email client that you actually like (like [Alpine](http://washington.edu/alpine)).

I'm one of those weird people who **love** the command line. It's in my blood. I highly dislike having to use outlook, especially since they're perfectly willing to allow access through OWA. So I stumbled across [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/) which seemed like the perfect solution. But looking through the [setup](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/linuxsetup.html) instructions, it didn't seem like there were any command line options.

And worst of all, when I try to run `./davmail.sh` at the command line I get this message:

```
Exception in thread "SWT" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at davmail.ui.tray.SwtGatewayTray$5.run(SwtGatewayTray.java:196)
```

Which looks an awful lot like an error with it trying to display the tray icon, which I don't have since I'm logged in over SSH. It also appeared not to do anything else - I tried telnetting into the IMAP/POP ports listed in `~/.davmail.properties` but got 'Connection refused'.

I wasn't able to find anything in the docs about running only from the command line. That brings me to my question:

Can I run DavMail in a command-line mode, **OR** are there any other (preferably *good*) command line interfaces to the OWA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a Davmail.properties file and call Davmail with that on the command-line. It is described nicely here:

http://davmail.sourceforge.net/serversetup.html